# IPTABLES: routing VPN users through transparent Squid

Tags: vpn, proxy, iptables, squid, pptpd

I'm hoping someone can help me out - I've been tearing my hair out over this!

I have pptpd and squid set up.  I want give these users access to the internet, but would like to send http traffic through a squid proxy.

Hopefully this rough diagram will give you an idea of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
VPN users connect to pptpd (via eth0)
    \ | /
      |
      |
     / \
 http   everything else
   |     |
   |     |
   |     |
squid    |
   |     |
    \   /
     \ /
      |
     NAT
      |
  internet  (via eth0)
```

If I set up the following iptables rule, users can connect to the internet:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

I can also connect to squid directly and it works as expected.

Now, I was hoping another simple rule would redirect all http traffic through squid:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i ppp+ -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3128
```

But this doesn't seem to work (I'm also hoping ppp+ is the correct formatting for a wildcard).  Http traffic is never redirected and bypasses the proxy.

Can anyone suggest how to get this working?

I don't really know much about this stuff I'm afraid.  I would also love some recommendations for ways in which I can debug the system, e.g. which log files to look at, tcpdump commands etc.  I find the iptables documentation extremely bewildering!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your rule is correct, you need to check if it is actually being matched.

```
iptables -t nat -vnL
```

Comment: Apologies, it was in fact working!  I was just being stupid.