# iptables route PPTP VPN through polipo http proxy

Tags: iptables, pptp, pptpd

I want to route http traffic of my local pptp server to use Polipo `http_proxy`.
So i found this QA : [IPTABLES: routing VPN users through transparent Squid](https://serverfault.com/questions/173232/iptables-routing-vpn-users-through-transparent-squid)

but i test on my system & change iptables rule from `3128` to `8123` like this :
`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i ppp+ -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8123`
When i want to get any webpage from browser i saw `Polipo` config page!

Am i missing to set iptables rules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, as far as I know Polipo can't be used as a transparent proxy. You must install a Squid proxy or another that supports that feature. You get the Polipo config page because you are accessing directly to that port without specifying in the headers that is a proxy request. Direct and proxy requests are made and handled differently.

I'd recommend you to use [Redsocks](http://darkk.net.ru/redsocks/). The page comes with good examples of how to configure it and is very reliable. Just be careful not to run out of file descriptors, it will spitting the "Too many open files" error and you'll have to restart it.

PS: You can't use any proxy to do the same thing with SSL (por 443), at least without messing with the clients.

Comment: why  i can't using polipo? what is different between squid & polipo?

Comment: Polipo can run in a "transparent" proxy config, but not as "intercepting proxy". This setup won't be possible with Polipo, sorry! Source:
http://www.pps.univ-paris-diderot.fr/~jch/software/polipo/faq.html

Comment: @Craig Ok,  how i can do my setup? i have only socks proxy & want to connect to it with pptp connect. i know that i can use openvpn instead of socks. so is there any software to convert http_proxy or socks into `tun` connection like openvpn?

Comment: Redsocks is what you need for redirecting traffic to a socks proxy. http://darkk.net.ru/redsocks/.

Comment: Thanks, that works. but i have question : when i set iptables to use `luser` (for example), it works fine, so now i want to set my pptp connection use `redsocks`. does pptp server run with `proxy` user?

Comment: It depends, you can find out by using ps aux | grep pptp and checking which  user is that process running with. It's usually the first field ;-)

Comment: thanks. if you want, you can update your answer for suggesting  `redsocks`.